# proving the set is dense by its geometric property

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

A set of points in the plane is invariant under the reﬂections across the sides of some given regular pentagon. Prove that the set is dense in the plane.

any idea? I don't know how to prove this! please help.

Comment: Looks funny, assuming your set is non-empty, take one point in it. We basically need to show the reflections (of the reflections [of the reflections...]) of this point is dense in the plane.

Comment: It's taken from [this book](https://books.google.it/books?id=VwrlnZ6QyHgC&pg=PA93).

Comment: It is a standard result about Coxeter groups, will be covered in any textbook on the subject, e.g. Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups - by Humphreys. Incidentally, it has nothing to do with real analysis, a better tag is Coxeter groups.